# OSMF Playing Event

Tags: actionscript-3, osmf

I am using OSMF and noticed when seeking almost immediately after, the "playing" event is fired causing my buffering icon to disappear almost instantly. The playing event is fired even though the video isn't actually playing. It takes a good 3-5 seconds before the video really begins playing. Has anyone heard of this?

Comment: I found using the `BufferingEvent.BUFFERING_CHANGE` event rather than the `MediaPlayerStateChangeEvent.MEDIA_PLAYER_STATE_CHANGE` is more accurate